# Why is plot_trisurf in Python in different data and platform not shown any plot?

Tags: python, plot

This is My code in python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':Final_X, 'y': Final_Y, 'z':Final_Z})
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(df.x, df.y, df.z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.1)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

[I](https://translateyar.ir) usually get the correct output from the plot, but When I input the bigger data , see something like this in the output:

```
<Figure Size 640*480 with 2 Axis>
```

And does not show anything else. Any help?

Comment: What is "sometimes"? Same input and environment, nonetheless randomly no graph? Graph is shown depending on the sample input? Graph is produced depending on the environment?

Comment: Yes, your right, I mean in different platform and different data input.

Comment: I edit this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently due to the resolution of some systems. Sometimes due to an error occurring after plotting